# Angular freeze the page - no click is allowed

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a HTTP request to the backend and I want to freeze the page. Actually, I want to freeze the entire screen. On the page, I have a button which redirect the user to another page. The button should not work. User should not be redirected until the http request is done. Is this possible in Angular?

Comment: something like a spinner would be more appropriate than just freezing/disabling content. This way the user can see that there's something happening and that he needs to wait until the reply to the request is processed. [ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner) or [material-spinner](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner) are quite simple to implement..

Comment: I have a spinner but the requirement is also to freeze the page until the request is done. I know that it doesn't make sense..

Comment: so just disable the backdrop like it's done with modals for example (given that your spinner is an overlay in the foreground)..

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't work for me. I know that I didn't give to much information but actually a page is formed by 2-3 component somehow.. Thank you very much for you time!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include details on what you have tried and *exactly* what doesn't "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in addition to spinner you can create a transparent/semitransparent overlay div and show it on on top of all other elements, so it prevents all user's actions. And simply show/hide it when you perform requests. There are plenty libraries, examples on ways to accomplish that. Here is CSS snippet to give an idea how CSS can look like:

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and in template:

```
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="requestInProgress">
</div>
```